# Two Oracle RMAN Backup between an EOB

Tags: backup, oracle19c, rman

I need to take two backups before and after the day end process. If the EOD process starts at 10.00 p.m. The backup should contain all the data right at 10.00 p.m. before starting the EOD and the backup process should not impact the EOD process as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

Please note that I need to retrieve RMAN backups for disk and then tape.

Comment: These are online / hot backups, capturing archive logs?

Comment: I think Point-in-time recovery can help. Right before EOD - performing Full db incremental level 0. When EOD is done - performing backup archive log (appear after previous full level 0. Then, want DB at before EOD, restore full level 0. Then, want DB at after EOD, restore full level 0, set SCN then recover to SCN after EOD.

Comment: @pmdba Yes they are.

Comment: See my answer below: the type (full or incremental) of backup and your specific schedule will mostly depend on your backup storage capacity, desired retention, or your desired Recovery Time Objective (RTO) and won't really affect your ability to restore to a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

A "snapshot" type of backup would only be necessary if you are running in NOARCHIVELOG mode, and you'd have to shutdown the entire database to do it as a "cold" backup (you can't get a logically consistent backup without transaction logs while the database is open for read/write activity). This would presumably impact your end-of-day process.

Assuming that the database is in ARCHIVELOG mode, and that you can run your backup as a "hot" backup while the database is up and running, you do not need to worry about the timing of your backup at all.

Run a backup whenever it makes sense based on system load or activity (being sure to backup the archive logs too), and if you need to recover from a backup later then recover to the exact point in time that you need - before or after your end-of-day process. See the documentation for Point in Time Recovery options: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-performing-flashback-dbpitr.html

The restore and recovery operation will restore from the backup and then re-apply all transactions to bring the database back to the desired point in time. The only thing the timing of the backup job would affect would be the number of transactions that might need to be re-applied after the data files are restored.